# How to make python click squares on memory game

Tags: python

someone know how to make python click squares on memory game?
EX:
I have this puzzle to memorize(The red squares are random):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5eFl.png

How do i make python to click red squares after they dissapear?

I managed to find if there is a red square on the screen.

```
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
from playsound import playsound

while 0:
    if pyautogui.locateOnScreen('model_square.png', confidence=1) != None:
        print("There is a red square")
        playsound('audio.mp3')
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print("No squares")
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: What module are you using to render them? Post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem and we might be able to help you.

Comment: @CarlHR I edited the post, that's what i managed to do, but how do i find the coordonates of red squares and click it?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you. I have no idea how to use these modules. If you posted the code from the start someone should've helped you by now. If it helps, try to insert the modules you're using as tags on the post. It helps to filter the posts on [the main page](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We help solve specific, programming problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: I asked for a concept, or how to done it, not the code, idk where to ask.

Answer (score 1):

`pyautogui.locateOnScreen('model_square.png', confidence=1)` will return (x,y) values of the given image if found on the screen.

`pyautogui.click(x,y)` will click on the given x,y.

So to code what you want to do we can simply declare a variable that will store x,y of the red squares found on the screen and then pass the variable in `pyautogui.click(variable)` to click the x,y coordinates of the red squares

So your code for that would be:

```
while 0:

    #This variable will return x,y of the image found on the screen
    red_square = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('model_square.png', confidence=1)
    if red_square != None:
        #click the x,y where the image is found on the screen
        pyautogui.click(red_square)
```

Comment: Thank You, I managed to figure it out. I used lists to memorize the coordinates than click them after 2 seconds.